# Задача с использованием одномерных массивов (С++)

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть задача (C++): "В одномерном массиве, состоящем из n действительных элементов, вычислить: 1) максимальный по модулю элемент массива; 2) сумму элементов массива, расположенных между первым и вторым положительными элементами.
Изменить программу что бы были использованы указатели."
Моих знаний c++ не хватает для решения этой задачки. Основное что не могу понять, это "вычислить максимальный по модулю элемент массива". Как это сделать в паскале я знаю, а тут - нет. Уже 3 дня мучаюсь с ней. Прошу помочь с задачей. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что получилось:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef float my_type_data;
typedef unsigned int my_type_counter;

void fun(my_type_data* array,my_type_counter array_size){

my_type_data maxval=0;
my_type_data sum=0;

cout<<endl;

my_type_counter i;
for(i=0;i!=array_size;++i){

   if(fabs(array[i])>fabs(maxval)) 
       maxval=array[i];

   cout<<array[i]<<",";

}//for

for(i=0;i!=array_size;++i){
   if(array[i]>0){
     sum-=array[i];
     break;
    }//if    
}//for

my_type_counter j;
for(j=i;j!=array_size;++j){
   sum+=array[j];
   if((array[j]>0)&&(i!=j)){
      sum-=array[j];
      break;
   }//if
}//for

cout<<" abs maxval="<<fabs(maxval)<<" sum="<<sum;
}

int main(){

my_type_data array1[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9};
my_type_data array2[]={-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9};
my_type_data array3[]={1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,8};
my_type_data array4[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
my_type_data array5[]={0,1,2,3,4,-100,5,6,7,8,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9};

fun(array1,sizeof(array1)/sizeof(my_type_data));
fun(array2,sizeof(array2)/sizeof(my_type_data));
fun(array3,sizeof(array3)/sizeof(my_type_data));
fun(array4,sizeof(array4)/sizeof(my_type_data));
fun(array5,sizeof(array5)/sizeof(my_type_data));


return 0;
}
```

Пример вывода:

> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9, abs maxval=9 sum=0
>
> -1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9, abs maxval=9 sum=0
>
> 1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,8, abs maxval=8 sum=-27
>
> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, abs maxval=8 sum=0
>
> 0,1,2,3,4,-100,5,6,7,8,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9, abs maxval=100
>   sum=0

Проверялось на http://cpp.sh/

Answer (score 1):

*Основное что не могу понять, это "вычислить максимальный по модулю элемент массива"*

Это просто найти элемент, у которого величина по модулю (вычисляемая с помощью `fabs()`) больше, чем у других элементов массива.